# WatiN can't find element by alt

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, c#-4.0, watin

I have a page that has the following line of code

```
<INPUT border=0 type=image alt="Use a password" name="SUBMIT-password.pss" src="docs/pics/en-us/useapassword_button.jpg">
```

My code is

```
using (var browser = new IE(path)) 
{
browser.Button(Find.ByAlt("Use a password")).Click();
Assert.IsTrue(browser.ContainsText("WatiN")); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `browser.Button`, use `browser.Image`

I setup a test file with your HTML snippet and the following works as you'd expect.  If I'm remembering correctly, in WatiN 1.? you'd use Button, but in WatiN 2.1 you use the Image class.

```
Console.WriteLine(browser.Image(Find.ByAlt("Use a password")).Name);
```

The above is tested on WatiN 2.1, IE9, Win7.